# check to see if next String tokenizer is empty

Tags: java, string, stringtokenizer

I'm having a problem, I'm using a text file that has over a million lines of numbers. the data is in the format below, some lines have 3 pieces of data while others have only 2. 
Each time the file gets to the data with only 2 bits, it seems to throw a null error (I'm using Try/catch to read the input stream)

If I remove the value 3 tokenizer then the program runs to the end. 
Do I need to put an if statement to check if there is another token after the 2nd line? if so - how??

```
            while ((getLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
              StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(getLine);
              String Value1 = tokenizer.nextToken();
              String Value2 = tokenizer.nextToken();
              String Value3 = tokenizer.nextToken();
            //Does some more things
            }
```

The data

```
    11      22      33
    44      55      
    77      88      99
    10      11
    13      14
    16      17      18
```

Comment: Did you by any chance try [the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#hasMoreTokens())? Guess not. Anyway, the `Scanner` class seems to be more trendy these days.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to check that there are still tokens in the tokenizer. You can do it like this:

```
String Value3 = tokenizer.hasMoreTokens() ? tokenizer.nextToken() : null;
```

Which will set `Value3` to `null` if there is no 3rd token. You might want to instead set it to the empty string.

The alternative is to use `getLine.split("\\s+")`, which will return an array of tokens. If there are only 2 values, the array will be of length 2. So be careful when attempting to read the 3rd value, which might not be present.

Answer (score 0):

If you try call `nextToken` a third time, when no token exists, it returns null. A better thing to do is to use `String.split`, where you can check the number of tokens. `StringTokenizer` is legacy anyway.

```
String[] tokens = getLine.split("\\s+");
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, how about using a try catch block like this..?

```
String Value1 = null, Value2 = null, Value3 = null;

try {
    Value1 = null;
    Value2 = null;
    Value3 = null;

    Value1 = tokenizer.nextToken();
    Value2 = tokenizer.nextToken();
    Value3 = tokenizer.nextToken();
} catch (NoSuchElementException nse) {
    // Do Nothing. Just continue..
}
// Does some more things

System.out.println(Value1 + Value2 + Value3);
```

You'll have a null "Value" if at all any token is not read.